# Python: Geocoding and extracting longitude, latitude, city

Tags: python, geocoding, arcgis, nominatim

I have a dataframe with addresses in a column and I am using the code below to extract longitude and latitude separately. Is there a way to extract longitude and latitude together as well as extract city using this same approach?

In address column of my "add" dataframe, I have addresses in the following format: "35 Turkey Hill Rd Rt 21 Ste 101,Belchertown, MA 01007"

I am using Python 3, Spyder IDE and Windows 10 desktop.

Sample data:

 Address 

 415 E Main St, Westfield, MA 01085

 200 Silver St, Agawam, MA 01001

 35 Turkey Hill Rd Rt 21 Ste 101,Belchertown, MA 01007

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim, ArcGIS, GoogleV3
#from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut

arc=ArcGIS(timeout=100)
nom = Nominatim(timeout=100)
goo = GoogleV3(timeout=100)

geocoders = [arc,nom, goo]

# Capture Longitude
def geocodelng(address):
    i = 0
    try:
        while i < len(geocoders):
            # try to geocode using a service
            location = geocoders[i].geocode(address)

            # if it returns a location
            if location != None:

                # return those values
                return location.longitude
            else:
                # otherwise try the next one
                i += 1
    except:
        # catch whatever errors, likely timeout, and return null values
        print sys.exc_info()[0]
        return ['null','null']

    # if all services have failed to geocode, return null values
    return ['null','null']


#Extract co-ordinates
add['longitude']=add['Address'].apply(geocodelng)


# Capture Latitude
def geocodelat(address):
    i = 0
    try:
        while i < len(geocoders):
            # try to geocode using a service
            location = geocoders[i].geocode(address)

            # if it returns a location
            if location != None:

                # return those values
                return location.latitude
            else:
                # otherwise try the next one
                i += 1
    except:
        # catch whatever errors, likely timeout, and return null values
        print sys.exc_info()[0]
        return ['null','null']

    # if all services have failed to geocode, return null values
    return ['null','null']


#Extract co-ordinates
add['latitude']=add['Address'].apply(geocodelat)
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of your input/source data?  Also, what is your objective?  Are you working from a flat file?

Comment: @Jeffrey I have updated my question above to show a sample of my pandas datatable.

Comment: Are there any of those addresses that currently fail in the systems that you are using?

Comment: @Jeffrey, None of the addresses are failing.

Comment: Please be patient if I seem slow.  If your system is already working, what is it that you want to accomplish?  I have worked in the address validation space for about 7 years.  I do this kind of stuff all day long.

Comment: @Jeffrey Thank you for being so responsive. Currently the code extracts longitude and latitude separately. I am thinking that it might be more efficient to extract longitude and latitude in one function vs. two separate functions. Also, some addresses have cities listed in an odd way, so I want to extract city from the geocoder function as well so everything is in the right format.

Comment: I'm not sure if the API that that you are calling allows that. I do know there are other address validation APIs that will extract for you the city and state confirm the address and return the latitude and longitude at the same time. Services such as Melissadata or edq or the addressdoctor...

Comment: I work at an address validation company called smartystreets

Comment: @Jeffrey Thank you for your response, I will look into the additional services that you have mentioned. I will also check out smartystreets.